# Laravel manually login always not match, in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

i keep having "not match" authentication using manually login with my laravel
here is my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Admin;
use Input;
use Validator;
use Auth;

class CobaLogin extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        return view('adminlogin');
    }

    public function username(){

    return 'username';

    }
    public function doLogin(Request $request){

        $username = $request ->input('username');
        $password = $request -> input('password');

        if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])){
          echo "yes match";

        }else{
            echo "not match";

        }
    }
}
```

and here is my model from admin table

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class Admin extends Authenticatable{
    protected $table = "admin";
}
```

here is my route

```
Route::get('loginadmin', 'CobaLogin@index');
Route::post('dologin', 'CobaLogin@doLogin');
```

here is my login blade file

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <form class="form-signin" action="{{ url('dologin')}}" method="POST">   
     {{ csrf_field() }}
      <br/><h2 class="form-signin-heading text-center">ADMIN LOGIN</h2>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email Address" required="" autofocus="" />
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required=""/>      
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"> Remember me
      </label>

      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>   
    </form>
  </div>
```

here is my auth.php file

```
'providers' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],
```

here is my register function

```
public function store(Request $request){
        $data=Input::except(array('_token'));

        // var_dump($data);
        $rule=array(
            'username' => 'required|unique:admin',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
            'cpassword' => 'required|same:password',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            );

        $message=array(
            'username' => 'This username already taken',
            'cpassword.min'=>'the password must at least 6 characters',
            'cpassword.same'=>'the password and confirm password must same',
            );

        $validator= validator::make($data,$rule,$message);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return redirect() -> to('adduser')->withErrors($validator);
        }else{

            $tambah = new Admin();
            $tambah->username = $request['username'];
            $tambah->password = Hash::make($request['password']);
            $tambah->email = $request['email'];
            $tambah->alamat = $request['alamat'];
            $tambah->lebih = $request['lebih'];
            $tambah->save();

        return redirect()->to('users')->with('success','Your Data Has Been Added');
        }

    }
```

and here is
[my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJK5b.png)
i have use Hash for encrypt password, and i think nothing wrong with regist, what do i miss?

i keep having "not match" as the answer from this

please help master

Comment: You should inclide your login blade file.

Comment: edited, sorry @PaulSantos

Comment: Have you tried replacing your `$request->input('key')` to `$request->get('key')`?

Comment: at first i used `$request->get('key')` before i use `$request->input('key')` @PaulSantos

Answer (score 0):

By default, Laravel uses `User` model for authentication. You can customize it by editing `config/auth.php`:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
```

Comment: Oh i forget to share my auth.php file. i have already change it here is my auth.php code 
`'providers' => [
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],`

Comment: still not match

Comment: @redwhale21 do you use `bcrypt()` for password when creating a new admin?

Comment: i'm using `Hash::make` while creating, i have already tried using `bcrypt()` before using `Hash::make` i think it's same

Comment: @redwhale21 yes, it's the same. Try to clear config cache with `php artisan config:clear`, maybe the `auth.php` config is cached or something. Also, how do you check if a user was authenticated or not? Just to be sure, try to use `dd(auth()->user());` instead of redirecting.

Comment: where do i place `dd(auth()->user());`  ? i haven't redirect it yet, i'm echo-ing it for checking

Comment: @redwhale21 oh, you're not authenticating a user (the third `attempt()` param). If you do not use redirecting, echoing will work fine.

Comment: i have tried to clear the config cache like you said but i still get the same problem

Comment: @redwhale21 so, just to be sure, it always shows `no match`? Please also update your question with the code you use for creating a new admin. Maybe it will help someone to find the problem.

Comment: @redwhale21 I can't look into `attempt()` source right now, but try to replace all `users` providers with `admin` in the `config/auth.php`

Comment: you know, maybe there is something wrong with my laravel project, idk maybe when i download it there are something missing that makes my authentication doesn't work. and i think the best answer for this is make a new project